# Windows 8 App C# 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Copy'

Tags: c#, string, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, copy

I'm currently working on a Windows 8 Application and need to utilize a string copy function, but C#'s built in String.Copy function is not working. Other String methods are there but Copy is absent.

I tried creating a generic C# console application and it worked just fine. Does a Windows 8 App project not allow System.String?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8 Pro and everything is updated.

Comment: If you think you need this method then you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Correct [Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copy.aspx) is not available in Windows Store apps.  If you look at the [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf.aspx), you can see that it doesn't have the "green store" glyph next to it.  [CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copyto.aspx) is available though, and I suppose the following would accomplish the same thing:

```
        s = "foo";
        t = new String(s.ToCharArray());
```

Comment: This creates a temporary array and can be inefficient is the input string is large, so I would recommend something like `string t = String.Concat(s, "");` in that case.